# Saber se input está focado ou não em tempo real

Tags: input, tempo-real

Olá, eu gostaria de fazer uma condição no javascript onde se o `input` estiver focado, um `label` fique `none` e quando a pessoa clicar fora dele e "desfocar", o `label` reapareça. Mas eu não sei fazer essa condição de verificar o tempo real, já pesquisei sobre

Sei que tem como pegar o valor do `.focus = true/false`, mas não sei em tempo real. Tem como fazer isso ?

```js
function busca() {
  var lupa = document.getElementById("lupa");
  var busca = document.getElementById("espacobuscar");
  var input = document.getElementById("buscaprod");
  input.autofocus = true;
  busca.style.cssFloat = "left";
  busca.style.display = "block";
  lupa.style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<div id="espacobuscar" class="fl">
  <!-- Aqui é o input da busca -->
  <input type="text" id="buscaprod" onkeyup="proc_produto_catalog(this.value)" placeholder="Buscar" />
  <div id="ls_produto_catalogo"></div>
</div>
<img id="lupa" onclick="busca()" src="../_imagens/lupa.png" />
<!-- Aqui é uma lupa que quando clicada, aparece o input -->

<div class="fr">
  <label id="label_mobile" class="fl" for="span_ped">Tipo de Pedido: </label>
  <!-- Esse é o label que tem que desaparecer quando a busca estiver com foco -->
  <div id="tipo_ped">
    <span id="span_ped"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Qual o seu código? O que você tem até agora?

Comment: Editei o post, coloquei o código

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode usar os eventos [focus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/focus) (quando o elemento recebe o foco) e [blur](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/blur) (quando o elemento perde o foco).

Exemplo:

```js
var teste = document.getElementById('teste');
var feedback = document.getElementById('feedback');

teste.addEventListener('focus', function() {
  feedback.hidden = true;
});

teste.addEventListener('blur', function() {
  feedback.hidden = false;
});
```

```css
*[hidden] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input id="teste">
<div id="feedback">Input sem foco</div>
```

Ou fazer isso apenas com CSS utilizando a pseudo classe [`:focus`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus):

```css
.teste + .feedback {
  display: block;
}

.teste:focus + .feedback {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input class="teste">
<div class="feedback">Input sem foco</div>
```

No exemplo acima foi utilizado o [seletor de elementos adjacentes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors).

Comment: Vou testar desse modo, já respondo aqui novamente

Comment: Atualizei com um exemplo apenas em CSS.

Comment: A volta dos que não foram! Vim para dar uma resposta só com CSS, mas vc já tinha resolvida :D

Comment: Tentei dos dois jeitos e não foi

Comment: @hugocsl quando estava adicionando a versão só com CSS achei que você já estivesse respondendo. hahahaha

Comment: @GabrielArcuri você sabe como funciona o seletor `+` ?? Meus exemplos estão funcionando, mas para aplicar ao seu caso é preciso alterar ou verificar se é o que você precisa mesmo. Apenas mostrei uma maneira resolver seu problema. Você precisa adaptar para seu caso

Comment: Pela sua estrutura HTML é a versão JS que vai usar.

Comment: Como meus elementos estão com `id`, eu alterei o `.` por `#` e os nomes `teste` e `feedback` para `buscaprod` e `label_mobile`

Comment: Usando javascript deu esse [erro](https://ibb.co/ioVuaq)

Comment: Cara, o conceito funciona.. o problema é o seu código. [Olha só](https://jsfiddle.net/qcohfru3/)

Comment: Deu para ver que funciona, vi aqui que de algum jeito o meu `input` e `label` estão retornando `null`. Vou ver o que está fazendo isso

Comment: Agradeço bastante pela ajuda